# Azure devops - Release Pipeline has no option for PHP 7.2 for Runtime Stack, but the Azure App service does

Tags: php, azure

When I am configuring my Azure pipeline (linux webapp, build-inn image), I only get a small subset for the Runtime stack when using the following template when setting up the stages in release pipeline 'Deploy a PHP app to Azure App Service and Azure Database for MySQL'

For my application I need PHP 7.2, which I can setup in the Azure Portal, under my App Service -> Application setting -> Runtime stack.

On every deploy I now have to check the Service still runs on 7.2 and did not revert back to 7.0

Does anyone know how can I setup my release pipeline so I can select PHP 7.2 for the stages in the release pipeline?
I did check to see if I could manipulate the pipeline template, but could not find anyting.

Thanks

Wilma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to set the PHP to 7.2 using the following devOps setting:

Post Deployment Action - Application and Configuration Settings - Configuration Settings

Add

-linuxFxVersion php|7.2

That achieved what I wanted as part of the DevOps pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your php version of your app in many ways apart from using azure portal->app settings

Other ways like

1. [Azure power shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-php-configure#azure-powershell-windows)
2. [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-php-configure#azure-cli)
3. [.user.ini file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-php-configure#how-to-change-the-built-in-php-configurations)

.....

[Refer here for the full details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-php-configure)